# Javascript/Jquery function to disable table row based on child element content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and in every row I have a cell (Example, for first row: `(id: ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c5)`. I need to check if this cell has value `1` then disable its row (i.e. `ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0` in above case).

```
(id: ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder)

row (id: ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0)
row (id: ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i1)
row (id: ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i2)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some _actual_ code and any relevant HTML.

Comment: what is the "table" ? HTML ? and what are you trying to disable ? an input / anchor ?

Comment: What do you mean by disable the row? Do you want to disable all controls in a particular row if a particular cell has a value of 1?

Comment: @ManseUK It's an asp.net gridview but as it is rendered it appears as a html <div> table in browser.

Comment: @Abbas Yes I want to disable all column in that row.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite then please add that to the question !

Comment: @JamWaffles Yes, I tried to but it is not working. Table is actaully comming in <div> instead of <table>

Comment: Well if it _was_ working, you wouldn't be asking a question about it. Please add more detail to your question instead of repeating yourself in comments.

Comment: @JamWaffles Thanks. I will bring that code to my local as I don't have rights to copy anything on VPN. I will get back again withing few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single line to do this with the `:contains()` selector. This example is assuming you're using `div` elements the way you described in comments.

```
$( "#ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder > div:contains(1)" )
    .attr( "disabled", "disabled");
```

If your HTML is a more complicated, you might want to be more specific and use the this line instead:

```
$( "#ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder > div[id^=ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i]:contains(1)" )
    .attr( "disabled", "disabled");
```

The first line finds any `div` under your `itemsHolder div` with the value of `1`. The second line only finds `div` elements with the `id` starting with `ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i` that have the value of `1`.

In this demo I set `background-color: gray;` for the disabled rows so you could see them.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/MULSv/

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder">
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0">
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c0" class="item">0</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c1" class="item">0</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c2" class="item">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i1">
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i1_c0" class="item">0</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i1_c1" class="item">1</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i1_c2" class="item">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i2">
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i2_c0" class="item">1</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i2_c1" class="item">0</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i2_c2" class="item">0</div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i3">
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i3_c0" class="item">0</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i3_c1" class="item">0</div>
        <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i3_c2" class="item">0</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
.item {
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

#### Script:

```js
$( "#ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder > div:contains(1)" )
    .attr( "disabled", "disabled").css( "background-color", "gray" );
```

#### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$('tr').find('td[id^="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch"]').each(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  if (self.text() === '1') {
    self.closest('tr').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance but I noticed that it is comming in <div> instead of table :-( is this going to effect ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Yes, it will have an effect. Please post the HTML that you wish to manipulate and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: it is like this <div id="ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0" <div id=" ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder" and <div id=" ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c6"

Comment: I think I have confused you.. it is like foreach div in ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder (this will get me the row inside the ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_itemsHolder)

Comment: and foreach inside the above foreach, i.e. for each row ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0 we need to find items, and based on the control text tl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c6 we need to make complete row [i.e. ctl00_MainContent_grdSearch_i0] disabled

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Please edit your question and put the HTML code you are talking about into it. This will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You said the table was really divs, so this works. See the fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/nickyt/XVttD

```
var rows = $("div[id*='MainContent_grdSearch_i0_c']");

rows.each(function() {
    var row = $(this);

    if (row.text() === "1") {
        row.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```